# Proof concerning a function continuous in an interval.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, continuity

I have been working on a question from Richard A. Silverman's Modern Calculus and Analytic Geometry which would appear quite simple except one case prevents me from making more progress.

The question is: Prove that if f is continuous in a half-open interval I, then $\{f(x)\mid x\in I\}$ is either half-open or closed but not open.

My approach was to show that there must exist at least one absolute extrema in I and then it would follow that I must not be open. But I noticed $\frac{\cos(1/x)}{x}$ values in $[-1,0)$ appear to be the open interval $(-∞,+∞)$. As well as be continuous in that interval. Note that in the text the infinite interval is said to be open. I am wondering why this above example is not true? Also where if there is a better approach to proving this?

Comment: Right. Or, if you want the range to be a *finite* open interval, take $f(x)=(1-x)\cos\frac1x$ on $(0,1].$

Answer (score 0):

f(x) is continuous iff for every open set in the image, the pre-image of that set is also open.  So, if the image of f(x) on some interval is open, the interval must be open.

That is if f(x) is continous, then

$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$ such that$|x-x_0|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|< \epsilon$

Any open set in the image is the union of some set of (open) $\epsilon$- balls, and each of those $\epsilon$-balls has a corresponding (open) $\delta$- ball in the pre-image.